# Can I restrict the sale of an item if one in the same or another category has already been added to the cart in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am currently volunteering for our local high school trying to help them with a website and need to know if there is a way to restrict an item if one has already been added to the cart. (restricting by category would be perfect).

Example:

Item 1 from the ABC category has been added. There are other items similar in the same category, I don't want the parent to be able to add another.  There are also similar items in category DFG that I don't want them to be able to add.

Comment: Please provide examples of the code or plugins you tried to implement, if you have no leads at least explain what you tried and what results you got.

Comment: A website for the high school based on woocommerce? Seems legit!

Answer (score 0):

Some simple thoughts I had is when you add an item you do check. It depends what you want to check. You can give an item another TAG that similar items have. When you add an item with that tag into the cart, it'll check to see if an item in the cart has that tag. If so, give an error message... or however you want to handle it.

SHOP
Item 1 (TAG: i1)
Item 2 (TAG: i2)
Item 3 (TAG: i1)

If I my cart if empty, and I add Item 1 into the shop, it will add. Then I go back into the shop and I decide to add Item 3. Since this the TAGS match of item one, I get an error. I go back, I add Item 2, the TAG is different, I am able to add this to cart.

If you have skill in PHP and MySQL, you should be able to do this pretty easily.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I am not very skilled in PHP or MySQL from a developer standpoint. I can usually figure my way around some thing that it already setup. I understand your logic in you reply Droidev, just not how to implement it.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to write a program for you. Perhaps you bit off more than you can chew. If you know the syntax, you just need to figure out the logic. If the items are already in a database, add a column and fill it in for each item through myphpadmin. From there, figure out how to call the database. Should be easy from there to figure out. Good luck bud